# Discord.js Forward DM message to specific channel

Tags: discord, discord.js

So, I need a way to forward a message sent in the bot's dm to a specific channel in my server.

this is the code that I got so far:

```
execute(message, args) {
    
      if(message.channel.type == "dm"){
        
        let cf = args.join(' ')
        const cfAdm = message.guild.channels.cache.get('767082831205367809')
        let embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle('**CONFISSÃO**')
          .setDescription(cf)
          .setColor('#000000')
      
        const filter = (reaction, user) => ['', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name);
        const reactOptions = {maxEmojis: 1};
        
        cfAdm.send(embed)
        .then(function (message) {
          message.react('')
          .then(() => message.react(''))
          /**** start collecting reacts ****/
          .then(() => message.awaitReactions(filter, reactOptions))
          /**** collection finished! ****/
          .then(collected => {
            if (collected.first().emoji.name === '') {
                const cfGnr = message.guild.channels.cache.get('766763882097672263')
                cfGnr.send(embed)
        
            }
        
          })
        });
      }
      
      else {
        message.delete()
         message.channel.send('Send me this in the dm so you can stay anon')
         .then (message =>{
             message.delete({timeout: 5000})
         })
      }
     
    }
```

But for some reason that I can't seem to understand, it gives me this error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' of null

If anyone can help me, that would be greatly apreciated.
Thanks in advance and sorry for the bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error here is that you are trying to call `const cfAdm = message.guild.channels.cache.get('ID')` on a `message` object from a Direct Message channel ( `if(message.channel.type == "dm"){`)

DMs don't have guilds, therefore `message.guild` is null and `message.guild.channels` does not exist.

You will need to first access the channel some other way. Luckily, Discord.js [has a way](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=channels) to access all channels the bot can work with* (you don't need to muck around with guilds because all channels have unique IDs):

`client.channels.fetch(ID)` or `client.channels.cache.get(ID)`

(I have not tested this but it seems fairly straight forward)

*See the link for caveats that apply to bots in a large amount of servers.